# How to stop Kafka DEBUG logs when Kafka lib is used as Keycloak module

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, slf4j, keycloak, jboss-logging

A keycloak module (including a kafka producer) is deployed to "keycloak-4.8.1.Final" server.

**My Problem**:

Even I used `INFO` log level, `DEBUG` messages are logging from Kafka library. So I want to stop messy Kafka debug logs form Keyclaok log file. Can someone PLEASE support me to overcome the issue.

I suspect there may be a conflict on logging mechanisms used in Keycloak (***jboss-logging***) & Kafka (***slf4j***) it self.

**Sample Log:**

```
10:10:40,642 INFO  [stdout] (kafka-producer-network-thread | InternalUserProvisioningProducer) 47473973 [kafka-producer-network-thread | InternalUserProvisioningProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Producer clientId=InternalUserProvisioningProducer] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=) to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
10:10:40,644 INFO  [stdout] (kafka-producer-network-thread | InternalUserProvisioningProducer) 47473975 [kafka-producer-network-thread | InternalUserProvisioningProducer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 28 to Cluster(id = 5N8ICZgiS-GewacYHMDtlg, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [])
```

**Kafka lib (in `pom.xml`):**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Keycloak Module config (`module.xml`):**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.my.core.internal-user-authenticator-module">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>

<resources>
    <resource-root path="internal-user-authenticator-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-common"/>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
    <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"/>
    <module name="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
    <module name="org.bouncycastle"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" export="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

**keycloak logging config (in `standalone.xml`):**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also make sure that the log level on the producer side is set to `INFO` as well. In `log4j.properties` file you should have something similar to

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stderr

log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
```

And pass this file to your Kafka Producer:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties
```